How to accept dash in type "number" with zod and react-hook-form?
I am using react-hook-form and zod, and want to accept dashes in type="number" (i.e range for example 4-6) or numbers like 4.
This is the field:
          <FormField
            control={control}
            name={`exercises.${index}.setsNumber`}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormControl>
                  <FloatingLabelInputWithIcon
                    id={`setsNumber-${index}`}
                    label="sets"
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />

How to do that?

An <input type="number"> cannot contain dashes between digits. This has nothing to do with Zod.

4-6 is not a valid number.

This is the standard XY Problem. You don't want to use a number input for a range. You may want to use a range input, or two number inputs, or a single text input.

Change the input type to text and use this schema for that field validation
But the downfall is the user can provide negative number.
const schema = z.object({
  numberField: z.string().refine((value) => /^\d*$/.test(value), {
    message: 'Must be a valid positive number',
  }),
});


I don’t want to use text field as on mobile it won’t open the numbers keyboard. I was wondering if there is another solution but I see there isn’t. I thought we can modify the number html5 validation with zod

Zod doesnt provide the dashed syntax for number but you can use inputmode="numeric" which can make user to have numeric keyboard
